# How to connect to remote hive server using spark2.0

Tags: hive

I m trying to connect to a remote hive server which is in different cluster using spark. Used both hive2 and thrift but no luck

```
val s = SparkSession.builder().appName("Man test").config("hive.metastore.uris", "jdbc:hive2://abc.svr.yy.xxxx.net:2171/default;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;principal=hive/_HOST@abc.AD.xxx.COM").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

val s = SparkSession.builder().appName("Man test").config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://xxxx.svr.us.yyyy.net:2000").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/apps/hive/warehouse").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
println("in method session created")
s.sql("show databases").show()
```

I m getting the below error when use jdbc:hive2

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

and when I use thrift :
`javax.security.sasl.SaslException`: No common protection layer between client and server.

please let me know if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by adding the following to the JVM options.

```
-Djavax.security.sasl.qop="auth-conf"
```

See: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/8604